# ZebraDesigner Pro 2 RFID button is grey out

Tags: c#, zebra-printers

There is issue on ZebraDesigner Pro 2, I can't use the RFID tag button, it is grey out, the RFID printer is Zebra ZD500R 203 dpi Printer, can anyone who has experience on this give me some help. or am I supposed to write command code directly, I am actually integrating printer with my C# program. Many Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing this problem, please do not change your printer name to any other than default, seems software will assume that the printer is not supportive of RFID tag writing.